# Format Text into Currency C# Monotouch IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I´m trying to figure out how to format a text field in a currency, like in the change of the field.

I´ve tried using. string.format, regex but nothing seems to help me.

I would need to get input(i can get this value, just need to format it) and change that to something like:

Input =  12345

Output = R$12.345,00

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is a example of what I´m trying:

```
string textValue = 12345;
CultureInfo ui_culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(ui_culture,"{0:C}",textValue));
```

It returns the 12345 always.

Comment: How about this: `string.Format(ui_culture, “{0:C}”, money_value);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried but i returns the same value i´ve passed without any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for you.

```
    string textValue = "12345";
    var d = Convert.ToDecimal(textValue);
    CultureInfo ui_culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("C", ui_culture));
```